# TicTacToe Misfortunes

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I'm a beginner in Java programming, and I'm trying to replicate TicTacToe as a program. I'm running into several problems, particularly with the computer's move as a random number generator and with stopping the loop when either the player or the computer wins. I believe both circumstances are going to utilize very similar coding (with how I'm doing it), and here's what I'm attempting, syntax-wise:

```
if (i >= 3)
{
   if ((((move)||(move2)||(move3)||(move4)||(move5))==((1)&&
        (2)&&(3)))||(((move||move2||move3||move4||move5)==
         (4&&5&&6))||((move||move2||move3||move4||move5)==(7&&8&&9)))){
                    System.out.println("You won!");
                }
}
```

I know this is very, very incorrect, but what's happening here (what I'm trying to achieve) is the board is segregated into nine numbered spaces, and when the player chooses "X", they go through a for loop five times; they can only possibly win after three moves (obviously), and I'm trying to get a group of either move, move2, move3, etc. to optionally equal one of the winning sequences (ex. the top three squares are numbered "1 2 3", so if the player or computer is able to choose all three of those numbers, I want the loop to stop and to simply output "You/The computer won"). I want to know how to designated a group of three moves as a group of possible wins, and how to get the random number generator to keep trying to output a move ("O") when the player or computer already chose one of the nine squares (and stop when it finally can; not keep replacing everything afterwards).

There's gotta be an easier way to do this. I've been wracking my brain for days, and I'm not coming up with any solutions. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For a start, instead of 9 variables, why not using an array? It would make it much easier to find a free spot for computer. It would also allow you to use 'for' loop to scan 3 rows, 3 columns and 2 diagonals.